# Vertical Line issue

Tags: html, css

I am facing issue while placing vertical line. Here I created fiddle and attached reference. Please help me out. Advance thanks.[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prabunivas/e6o446o3/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this a couple of ways:

1) The margins are keeping your line from extending.  Using padding instead will solve that.

2) More importantly, since this is tabular data the markup should use tables.  It will also give you the look you seek while being semantic and not requiring all the extra classes/css.

Here is the updated jsfiddle using tables: http://jsfiddle.net/haltersweb/e6o446o3/3/

The code is below as well:

```css
table {
    margin: 10px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
.accessibly-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
 display: block;
 visibility: visible;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 margin: -1px;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Arrived</th>
                <th>RAC Status</th>
                <th>Luggage</th>
                <th><span class="accessibly-hidden">Name</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option selected="selected">Not Enrolled</option>
                        <option>Enrolled</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option selected="selected">1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Doe, John
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option>Not Enrolled</option>
                        <option selected="selected">Enrolled</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option selected="selected">2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Doe, Jane
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```